# How to apply Fisher's exact test to each column of count data split into two categories?

Tags: r, loops, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

I have count data (columns) in the form of presence/absence (1/0) of various genes in different samples that belong to one of two categories.
I am trying to do a Fisher's (fisher.test) for each gene and output the data into a separate table. Because I have over 100 genes (names are more complicated than Gene1, Gene2,...), I would like to apply the test to each column containing gene count data, skipping the first few columns that contain categorizing metadata, and have the output data for all genes go into a separate table, labelled with the column name used to calculate the data.

The answers I have found have tabulated and grouped counts rather than columns of raw ungrouped count data, so the layout is quite different.

I have tried a few different things, like a for loop, apply() with a function in it, etc., but because the column name is part of the calculation formulas, and because I need to skip the first 8 columns of metadata, it's become quite complex and I can't get it to work properly.

Sample data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(sampleID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                     category = c("high", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low"),
                     Gene1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                     Gene2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                     Gene3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

The simple form of the test, applied to just one column, and data output into console rather than saved, worked:

```
matrix = with(mydata, table(category, Gene1))  
fisher.test(with(mydata, matrix))
```

I tried something like:

```
for(x in 3:ncol(mydata)) {
  matrix = with(mydata, table(category, x))
  fisher.test(with(mydata, matrix))
}
```

I tried using apply:

```
df = mydata
output.file <- fxn = function(x){
  matrix = with(df, table(Site, x))
  fisher.test(with(df, matrix))
}

apply(x = df,
      FUN = fxn,
      MARGIN = 2)
```

I know it's wrong, but I don't know how to make it right.
PS. I'm pretty new to R, so if you can explain how your code works, it will help me to replicate it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** to address genes with no variability: Try this:

```
mydata %>%
  select(-sampleID) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -category, names_to = "gene") %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
   # filter out genes with no variability
  filter(sum(value) > 0 & sum(value) < n()) %>%
  summarise(fisher_test = list({
    if(sum(value) == n() || sum(value) == 0) {
      # if all values are 1's or 0's, return NA for p-value and estimate
      tibble(method = "Fisher's exact test", alternative = "two.sided",
             estimate = NA_real_, p.value = NA_real_)
    } else {
      # perform Fisher's exact test for the remaining genes
      tidy(fisher.test(table(category, value)))
    }
  })) %>%
  unnest(fisher_test) %>%
  mutate(odds_ratio = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  select(-method, -alternative)
```

**First answer:**
Here is a `tidyverse` `broom` combination:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

mydata %>%
  select(-sampleID) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -category, names_to = "gene") %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarise(fisher_test = list(tidy(fisher.test(table(category, value))))) %>%
  unnest(fisher_test) %>%
  mutate(odds_ratio = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  select(-method, -alternative)
```

```
  gene  estimate p.value conf.low conf.high odds_ratio
  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Gene1    1.81        1  0.0469      176.        6.11
2 Gene2    0.707       1  0.00640      78.2       2.03
3 Gene3    1.81        1  0.0469      176.        6.11
```

Comment: Its a 2*2 and very small data.

Comment: @TarJae, this works, thank you! One issue is that some genes are present in all samples (value column is all 1's), and when that happens, I get the error "Caused by error in `fisher.test()`: ! 'x' must have at least 2 rows and columns".  Is there a way to avoid getting an error message and just have it skip that gene or something?

Comment: Please see my update. If it does not work please start a new question!

Comment: @TarJae I started a new question as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825583/how-to-modify-fishers-exact-test-on-count-data-to-include-a-post-hoc-test , but wondering where in your code I could add a post-hoc test like fdr.

Answer (score 1):

```r
lapply(mydata[-(1:2)],function(x)fisher.test(table(mydata[,2],x)))
#> $Gene1
#> 
#>  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#> 
#> data:  table(mydata[, 2], x)
#> p-value = 1
#> alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>    0.0469432 175.8462095
#> sample estimates:
#> odds ratio 
#>   1.810068 
#> 
#> 
#> $Gene2
#> 
#>  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#> 
#> data:  table(mydata[, 2], x)
#> p-value = 1
#> alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>   0.006400778 78.183984029
#> sample estimates:
#> odds ratio 
#>  0.7071212 
#> 
#> 
#> $Gene3
#> 
#>  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#> 
#> data:  table(mydata[, 2], x)
#> p-value = 1
#> alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>    0.0469432 175.8462095
#> sample estimates:
#> odds ratio 
#>   1.810068
Ā
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'Ā' not found
```

## EDIT:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Gene'))%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  summarize(broom::tidy(fisher.test(table(category, value))))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   name  estimate p.value conf.low conf.high method                       alter…¹
#>   <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                        <chr>  
#> 1 Gene1    1.81        1  0.0469      176.  Fisher's Exact Test for Cou… two.si…
#> 2 Gene2    0.707       1  0.00640      78.2 Fisher's Exact Test for Cou… two.si…
#> 3 Gene3    1.81        1  0.0469      176.  Fisher's Exact Test for Cou… two.si…
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​alternative
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to get the output data into a new data frame with the gene, p-value, confidence.interval, and odds.ratio?

Comment: what does 'name' refer to on line 4?

Comment: @ABee run the first 2 lines of code, and you will see that there is a column called `name`